# Get Text From Selected using selectize

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I've tried this:

```
var eventHandler = function() {
    return function() {
        console.log($select.val());
    };
};
var $select = $('.selectize').selectize({
    create          : true,
    onChange        : eventHandler()

});
```

Which get me the value of the selected option but I need the text. When I do this:

```
console.log($select.val().text());
```

I get an error. I've tried other things to no avail. How do I get the selected text?

Answer (score 9):

`select_option.getItem(select_option.getValue())[0].innerHTML;
select_option = $select_option[0].selectize;`
 to get text value of a specified dropdown option.

`this.getItem(value)[0].innerHTML` to get text value of current dropdown option

Answer (score 7):

the easiest way is to use `onChange` event and get text from selected option

JS:

```js
$(function(){
$('#select').selectize({
     create: true,
     sortField: {
      field: 'text',
      direction: 'asc'
     },
     onChange:function(value){
      $(".log").append("Value:" + value + "<br />");
      $(".log").append("Text:" +$("#select option:selected").text() + "<br />");
     },
     dropdownParent: 'body'
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/css/selectize.default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/js/selectize.js"></script>


<select id="select" class="control-form" data-placeholder="Select a person...">
<option value="">None</option>
<option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
<option value="1">Nikola</option>
<option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
<option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
</select>
<div class="log"></div>
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/bson6dj9/)

Comment: This will only work on a single-select list not multi-select.

Answer (score 7):

you can get selected text by :

```
$('select').selectize({
         onInitialize: function (selectize) {
            selectize.on('change', function (value) {
                 var item = this.$input[0];
                 var selected_text = $(item.selectize.getItem(value)[0]).text();
              });
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

So I got it working kind of. It's damn kludgey and there has to be a better way. There's a method `getValue()` but there's isn't a corresponding `getText()` method.

```
var eventHandler = function() {
    return function() {
        var something = selectizeControl.getItem(selectizeControl.getValue());
        console.log(something.text());
    };
};

var $select = $('.selectize').selectize({
    create          : true,
    onChange        : eventHandler()

});
var selectizeControl = $select[0].selectize
```

Comment: can you get multiple selected

Answer (score 4):

You could get the text with this line:

```
ddlcontrol[0].selectize.getItem(ddlcontrol[0].selectize.getValue()).text();
```

where **ddlcontrol** comes from:

```
var ddlcontrol = $('#ddCountry').selectize({
 valueField: 'id',
 labelField: 'name',
 searchField:['name']
});
```

Hope it works for you!.

Answer (score 3):

This thing can be added via prototype:

```
Selectize.prototype.getText = function () {
    return this.getItem(this.getValue()).text();
};
```

If someone would need method `setText` (like corresponding method `setValue`) it can be added this way:

```
Selectize.prototype.setText = function (text) {
    var selectize = this;
    $.each(this.options, function (propertyName, propertyValue) {
        if (propertyValue[selectize.settings.labelField] === text) {
            selectize.setValue(propertyName);
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

- Retrieving the selected value : `selectize_obj.getValue()`
- Retrieving the selected text  : `$(selectize_obj.getItem(value)).html()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `$('select[class*="selectize"] option')` worked for me. I used `*=` because I often use multiple classes at a time on elements ([more on jQuery selectors/wildcards at w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)). Otherwise, if using *id* or *name*, I would use `$('select[id="selectize-id"] option')` or `$('select[name="selectize-name"] option')` respectively.

Then, to get the option value, I add on `.text()` and to get the option key I add on `.val()`.

**Example**

If I have a list of countries and "usa" is the currently selected value with "United States" being the currently viewable text, I would do the following:

- `$('select[class*="selectize"] option').val()` to return "usa"
- `$('select[class*="selectize"] option').text()` to return "United States"

**Possible Alternative**

Simply using the basic id selector -- as in `$('#selectize-id option')` -- did not work. However, using the basic class selector -- as in `$('.selectize-class option')` -- did seem to work ([more on attribute selectors on w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)). Perhaps someone can comment on the difference between the two (`$('#someId)` vs `$('element[id="someId"]')`) that causes this.

Answer (score 0):

this trick worked for me when using **single item** selectize:

```
var selectedText_ = "";
var val_ = $("#mySelect")[0].selectize.items[0]; // get first value
if (val_)
    selectedText_ = $("span[data-value=" + val_  + "] div").text(); // get text
```

You can manipulate the code above using a loop if you want to select all Texts from your **multi-value** selectize